# InvalidResponse error in bigquery load_table_from_file

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a set of csv data into a BigQuery from a BytesIO object, but keep getting an error `InvalidResponse: Response headers must contain header 'location'`

Here is my code

```
# self.database = authenticated bigquery.Client

config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
config.skip_leading_rows = 1
config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
config.allow_jagged_rows = True
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("date", "DATE", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("page_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED")
]
# ... Appending a list of bigquery.SchemaField("name", "INTEGER")
config.schema = schema

table = self.get_or_create_table(name, config.schema) # returns TableReference

file = self.clip_data(local_fp, cutoff_date) # returns BytesIO

job = self.database.load_table_from_file(
    file, table,
    num_retries=self.options.num_retries,
    job_id=uuid.uuid4().int,
    job_config=config
) # Error is here.
```

I have tried searching around but I cannot find any reason or fix for this exception.

```
InvalidResponse: ('Response headers must contain header', 'location')
```

Comment: Reading through more documentation, I discovered that `load_table_from_file` accepts a `location` parameter, but setting this unfortunately did not mitigate the error in any way.

Comment: Retraction of last comment, my Spyder console didn't refresh the file properly, `location` is exactly what I needed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by not providing a `location` in the `load_table_from_file` method.

```
location="US"
```

was enough to fix the problem.

Comment: I do set `location` but still get the same error. Any ideas?